# Android - WebView shows encrypted content of pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-webview

I am developing an android application in which I tried to load pdf into Webview from the URL mentioned below,

```
http://ipAddress/SD_BIO/showDocument.jsp?fileName=HIPAA%20Authorization%20Form.pdf&attachmentType=STUDY_INFORMED_CONSENT_FORMS&attachmentTypeId=120&documentId=412
```

I tried in the following ways ,

```
((WebView) findViewById(R.id.pdf)).getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(
                true);

        ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.pdf)).getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(
                true);
        ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.pdf)).getSettings().setPluginState(
                PluginState.ON);
        ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.pdf))
                .loadUrl("http://ipAddress/SD_BIO/showDocument.jsp?fileName=HIPAA%20Authorization%20Form.pdf&attachmentType=STUDY_INFORMED_CONSENT_FORMS&attachmentTypeId=120&documentId=412");
```

The Webview is loaded , but encrypted like below,
[image]

Then I modified the `loadURL` like below,

```
((WebView) findViewById(R.id.pdf))
                .loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://ipAddress1/SD_BIO/showDocument.jsp?fileName=HIPAA%20Authorization%20Form.pdf&attachmentType=STUDY_INFORMED_CONSENT_FORMS&attachmentTypeId=120&documentId=412");
```

But,it shows **"No Preview Available"**. Also,I could able to see some thirdparty libraries.But,client does not want any third party libraries .

Please help me find the solution .

Comment: Does the PDF reads normally in your Android's browser? Maybe have a look at a library to show PDFs like https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: Oops !If I open in browser , one .jsp file starts downloading and if I open that also has encrypted content.please tell me what will be the issue ?

Comment: Issue is that you need a PDF reader. See CommonsWare answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` does not show PDF files. If `http://ipAddress/SD_BIO/showDocument.jsp` is returning a PDF file, `WebView` has no means of displaying it.

> But,client does not want any third party libraries .

Your client does not have very many options:

- Use third-party PDF rendering code.
- Use a third-party PDF viewer app.
- Serve up something other than PDF, such as HTML.
- On Android 5.1+, [try `PdfRenderer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html), though that is really designed for print previews.
- Hire developers to write a custom PDF renderer from scratch (hundreds of developer-months' worth of work).